# messageDeleted event not being triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have just started creating a discord bot using discord.js and was trying out the events and came across an issue. The `messageDeleted` event doesn't trigger when a message gets deleted.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new discord.Client();
const token = 'bot_token';

Client.on('ready', function(){console.log('Logged on!')});

Client.on('messageDeleted', function(message, channel){
    console.log('Test, a message was deleted.');
});

Client.login(token);
```

It never prints out 'Test, a message was deleted.' when I delete a message. **note** I've tried deleting messages already in chat before running the code and deleting messages I created after running the code to see if that was the issue. Still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're putting an event on `messageDeleted` instead of [`messageDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=messageDelete). 

Which is a wrong event listener and doesn't catch the correct emitted one.

Comment: Wow that worked! But why would it be 'messageDeleted' on here?
 http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#events

Comment: Looks like at some point in the past all the docs were done in reStructuredText https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/tree/5a5316dc66cecfd1dcd6fac021c21ffd6fcf85c7/docs and were hosted on readthedocs.io. From what I'm seeing, this is now the source of the site: https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js-site and it's on js.org. I really don't  know the history of the project though. I just googled around a little bit to figure out that.

Comment: @CyberLX I actually looked one more time. The front page of [that documenation](https://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) actually says that it's for discord.js before 9.0.0. If you follow their link to where the new documenation is, it looks like it goes to another spot they abandoned, which now links to the current location.

Comment: @CyberLX If this solved your issue, do you mind marking it as the answer with the checkmark under the vote arrows? That'll mean this question will show up as answered and go out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time researching and testing this MessageDeleted topic. In my configuration, I don't have the "Manage Messages" permission set for Channels. I don't allow anyone to delete messages for anyone else. However, this does not prevent someone from deleting their own message. With "Message Manage" turned off, when a Guild Member deletes their own Message, the "MessageDeleted" never fires. As soon as you grant the "Manage Messages" permission and the member deletes their own message, the MessageDeleted event fires. Anyone with the "Manage Messages" permission will cause the MessageDeleted event to fire.